# Getting the native "share sheet" to pull up when item button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, rss, ios-sharesheet

I am working on finishing an rss reader app for my internship and the last thing I need to implement is a "Share" button on the top right corner of the uiwebview that displays the mobile site link for the article.

Here is a screenshot of the web view navigation controller:

[image]

I used a free open source code project to get this done since I don't have much experience in xcode and I had to get it done in a short amount of time. As you can see from the screenshot, the uiwebview covers the whole controller and I couldnt find anyway to simply put a button on the uinaviagtionbar since it's not there. When I placed an "Item" under the "Navigation Item" into the detail scene in the left panel and ran the project, it does show up in the web view's navigation bar. It just says "Item" and when clicked does nothing obviously:

[image]

So my question is, how do I programmatically, or any other way, set it so that when clicked this share sheet will show up:

[image]

I have been on this all week trying various different ways from other answers and the minimal amount of info from the web. Nothing seems to be working for me and there isn't any clear tutorials on this. I only have two days left to complete this app and this is the last thing I need to it do for it to be ready. If anyone would be kind enough to take the time and possibly provide some sort of step-by-step so that I may also learn (and have this answer to view for future endeavors) I would be extremely appreciative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code inside your button action

```
-(void) showSharingActivity {
    NSString *string = @"string to share";
    NSURL *URL = [NSUrl urlWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in"];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
      [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[string, URL]
                                        applicationActivities:nil];
    [navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                          animated:YES
                                        completion:^{
      // ...
    }];
}
```

And add a button to your navigation bar like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSharingActivity)];          
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

Comment: How do I set the button as an action? All I have so far is just placing the "Item" button under "Navigation Item" in the right panel

Comment: I am getting errors when implementing this: 

"No known class method for selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' " 

and at "NSString *string = ...;    
NSURL *URL = ...; 

I get "expected expression"

Comment: Edited, check @Christophorus

Comment: Ok, the top edit works now, but unfortunately the line "[navigationController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                          animated:YES" 

is still giving me:

 "No known class method for selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion:'

Comment: Replace navigationController  with self

Comment: Thank you, it works! Now, one little last thing, how do I get the title of the artice to share?  I re-worked the code like this :     NSString *string = @"string to share";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:feedURL]; As you can see, I can get the link of whichever article to share now instead of the google example you posted by using my "feedURL". But for some reason when I replace the code for the "string to share" with my "feedTitle" it crashes

Comment: How are you passing your feedTitle?